# XRDP not running Gcompris. Mate desktop

Tags: mate, xrdp

XRDP works fine for other applications.
Gcompris opens fine locally.

I tried using vino as an alternative and that's mostly okay. I need audio for gcompris and other applications to really be useful. To my knowledge I can't do that with vino. Also, since vino lets the client take over the active desktop I can't have concurrent users like xrdp will allow. It's not ideal to need more than one VM for this, but that would be fine if it makes things easier.

My end goal is to have a single VM running applications from the edubuntu bundle. I need a way to have more than one client log in remotely and have audio. It's all happening on my home network so security is not an issue. I'm using fire tablets as the clients. I can also use Nook tablets. It would be okay to just connect to a single application at a time, but I'm not sure if I would want that just yet. I saw where there are various ways to redirect audio if you are using VNC, but I don't necessarily want to head down that path if it's just something simple with XRDP and the gcompris application that can be resolved.

Versions:

Currently testing this on Ubuntu 16.04.1 32 bit with Mate desktop

on an old IBM Thinkpad R52

Vino 3.8.1-0ubuntu9.2

XRDP version 0.6.1-2ubuntu0.3

Gcompris 15.02-1.1ubuntu1

Client 1 windows 10 mstsc.exe to xrdp

Client 2 Fire HD 8 (6th Gen)
  Connecting with 2x rdp, Remote Desktop Manager, vnc client. All from the Amazon app store.

Client 3 SM-T230NU Nook Android 4.4.2
  Connecting with aRDP free, aFreeRDP,  VNC Viewer, androidVNC. All from the Google Play Store.

The Thinkpad already had xrdp installed and working. It also already had gcompris installed and working before I decided to play with this. I plan to put everything on a VM running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 with the full Edubuntu suite (maybe a subset) after I know what I need to do to get this all working. I already made the VM with a minimal install. I just don't want to muddy it up if I can test everything on the Thinkpad.

---

Some progress of sorts.
I was able to open gcompris over xrdp from the terminal. I made a script on the desktop for that. I'm hoping this isn't an issue for the other applications. I was able to open it from mstsc.exe on my win 10 box by just clicking the script. Still no sound redirection.

Another issue:
I found the current MS RDP app will not connect to XRDP at all and it is a long standing problem. I could have used a different RDP. I did a little reading.

I found an old apk version here. 
https://microsoft-remote-desktop.en.uptodown.com/android/versions
I went from "Microsoft Remote Desktop_v8.1.74.397_apkpure.com.apk" 
to "microsoft-remote-desktop-8-0-12-25288-en-android.apk". It's not quite the same, but it works.

---

My last issue, before I start playing with the 18.04 VM, seems to be redirecting the audio. I'm looking at this for now:
https://github.com/neutrinolabs/pulseaudio-module-xrdp/wiki/README

---

I have tried a lot of things to get this going. I did get xrdp to work on the latest LinuxLite running Ubuntu 18.04. The sound does not work.

I ran through this.
https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12469
The sound still does not work. The steps are easy to follow, which makes me think something is missing.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Updated question. Any help is appreciated.